# foreach in foreach in if blade php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```xml
@foreach ($capacityGroups as $capacityGroupFather)

@foreach ($exampleProjects as $k => $exampleProject)

@foreach ($exampleProject->capacityGroups as $j => $exampleCapacity)

@if ($exampleCapacity->id == $capacityGroupFather->id)
```

Only the first result of the loop

```xml
<div class="carousel-item active">
```

The rest of the loop

```xml
<div class="carousel-item">
```

We have the example Projects collection, each of which has capacityGroups.
I need to bring all the example Projects for each capacity Group. But the first of each goes into a special div (`carousel-item active`)
and the rest of each goes into (`carousel-item`) how can I fix this problem

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [the loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable).

```xml
@foreach ($exampleProjects as $k => $exampleProject)
    <div class="carousel-item{{ $loop->first ? ' active' : '' }}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: doesn't blade have even a helper for creating class lists conditionally?

Comment: I don't *think* so. Can't think of anything like that at the moment. This is as simple as it can get.

Comment: I suppose you can make a component or a custom directive but that seems to be too much work when the `$loop` variable already covers this particular case. Using an `@if` directive instead of the ternary operator can also work but it will look uglier.

Comment: Sure it will look uglier. As far I've seen a dedicated example is `@error...` but it also wraps around `@if` and then needs some closing parts. nothing is won compared against the ternary. perhaps actually the best you can do!

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. I still have problems since the loop only works for position 0 of ALL exampleProjects, but what I need is for it to bring the first result of the exampleProject for each of the capacityGroups. To put you more on topic, the capacityGroups are 5, I need the first result of each of those capacityGroups to have the div carrousel-item active, while the others have carrousel-item. Edit the code since I am missing a first foreach so that it is better understood